# Email Contact Form Not Working

Tags: email, tags, email-contact-form

EE 5.2.6

I have the default email contact from set up. Looks like this:

```
{exp:email:contact_form 
  form_class='contact-form' 
  return='{site_url}index.php/{p_url}/thanks' 
  redirect='0' user_recipients='no' 
  recipients='myrecipient@yahoo.com'
}
<input name="name" type="text" value="{member_name}">
<input class="required" name="from" type="text" value="{member_email}">
<input name="subject" type="text" value="">
<textarea class="required" name="message" cols="" rows=""></textarea>
<input class="comment_button shake transformer" type="submit" value="Send e-mail">
{/exp:email:contact_form}
```

When I test this the form itself seems to work fine - it processes the submission, goes to a "Your message has been sent" page which automatically redirects back to the contact page with a thank you message. All of this is working fine, but I do not receive the email.

I have been checking the exchange here for answers, so here's a checklist of things I've done.

- Email add-on is installed
- Spam add-on is installed
- Tried adding this to the form but resulted in error when form submitted

```
    <input type="hidden" name="from" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="Email Contact" />
```

I do not have a lot of experience with email forms at all so it is totally likely that I don't have some setting set correctly.

Please help.

Comment: Not a solution, but something to test.  In the EE control panel, go to the Developer / Utilities menu item.  The screen you go to is a simple form to send an email from your EE site - it uses the same transport as the email form.  Send yourself a short message and see if that arrives: if it does not, fix your site's email sending settings!  Also, according to docs `redirect="0"` is not a thing - do you mean `redirect="none"`?

Comment: Thanks, jcogs. I went to the utilities page and sent an email from there to myself. I got a mailer-daemon "Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender". It says "This is the mail system at host {domain.i.dont.know.com}". I looked up "554 5.7.9 message not accepted for policy reasons" and got this: https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN7253.html  I've created an email with my domain, but now I'm not sure how to get that to run using the yahoo account I set up. I think this is the problem, but as I said I'm not experienced with email stuff so I don't really know!

Comment: The answer very much depends on things not known in your question - such as how you have configured outbound mail on your EE site, and what outbound email service you plan to use.  Some hosts will not allow connections from hosts to external SMTP services, others will (for example).  One thing to try is changing the `Settings / Outbound Email / Protocol` setting to phpmail temporarily and see if your test message sends.  The phpmail setting will use whatever the default mail sending mechanism for your host is: if that doesn't work talk to your host!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I contacted my host and talked to them about setting up email. I was able to test the form using an address set up by them and it worked just fine. The only issue now is getting that account linked up with my yahoo account, which doesn't appear to be possible with yahoo, so I'll probably have to set up some other email client to use. Thanks again!